# HIVE - How to convert multiple rows to multiple columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, hive

I try to convert multiple rows to multiple columns.
Here is the example:

- Input:

[image]

- Output:

[image]

When the value of `exp_ver` is determined, I can achieve it by `collect_list` and hardcoded approach. Unfortunately, the value of `exp_ver` is not always known in advance, so the hardcoded approach cannot be used in all cases.

Is there any way to do this? thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use `lateral view explode()` in sql